# Como recuperar ultimo registro inserido em banco de dados Firebird?

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

Minha tabela Venda possui um campo Codigo com auto-incremento e preciso recuperar esse codigo para inserir em uma tabela associativa.

```
string sql = $"INSERT INTO VENDA(NRO_VENDA,DATA_VENDA,VALOR_TOTAL_PRODUTOS,VALOR_ACRESC‌​IMO,VALOR_DESCONTO,V‌​ALOR_TOTAL_VENDA,COD‌​IGO_CLIENTE)VALUES({‌​entidade.nroVenda},'‌​{entidade.DataVenda}‌​',{entidade.ValorTot‌​alProdutos},{entidad‌​e.ValorAcrescimo},{e‌​ntidade.ValorDescont‌​o},{entidade.ValorTo‌​talVenda},{entidade.‌​Cliente.Codigo})";
ConnectionFirebird.ExecComand(sql);
```

Minha tabela `Venda` possui o campo `Codigo` com auto-incremento na qual quero recuperar esse valor.

Ref: procuro algo como o Last_Insert_Id do Mysql

Comment: Poste o trecho desse código!?

Comment: ultimo registro? faz um select usando MAX(CODIGO) já que é auto incremento

Comment: Copiei o seu comentário para o corpo da pergunta.

Comment: @TotallyUncool, Usar MAX() nao é boa prática. Primeiro que não garante que terá o ultimo registro criado, principalmente se for um banco concorrido, seguindo que se tiver muitos registros, será extremamente demorado o returno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver usando Firebird 2, já possui o `RETURNING` com a clausula `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (...) values (...) RETURNING pk;

PK
===========
32
```

Se for um Firebird anterior, e se tiver colunas de auto incremento, vc pode recuperar com o `gen_id()`:

```
select gen_id(GENERATOR_NAME, 0)
  from rdb$database;
```

Porém, não é certo que vc terá o valor do ID do registro que vc quer, vc terá o último ID. Mas se for um banco concorrido, vc terá o ID mais recentemente criado. A unica maneira que ter o ID do registro recém criado, com certeza, é recuperando o "proximo ID que será criado na sequencia" e usa-lo no `INSERT`:

```
declare variable id bigint;
select gen_id(GENERATOR_NAME, 1)
  from rdb$database
  into :id;

INSERT INTO t1 (pk, ...) values (:id, ...);
```